# See Pike raid status in ESXi 6.7

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, megaraid

I am using ESXi 6.7 and have an Asus Pike 3108 card in the server.  When I browse the Host | Monitor | Hardware | Storage I can see:

Avago (LSI) MegaRAID SAS Invader Controller #0

But the status is unknown.  My understanding is that the VIB (lsi-msgpt3 I think) is included with Esxi 6.7.  Do I have to enable/load this VIB manually?

What do I need to do to gain visibility into the RAID status?